# How to change a cursor to wait while table is loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

So I created a refresh button that calls a function called `refreshTable()`.  The table it refreshes contains a large amount of data so I want the cursor to change to a wait cursor until the table is done loading.

Currently I have:

```
<asp:Button ID="RefreshBtn" Text="Refresh" OnClick="refreshTable" style="cursor:wait" runat="server"/>
```

which changes the cursor to wait when I **hover** over top of the button rather than when I **click** on it.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a `div` absolute positioned with `cursor: wait` on top of everything for the time loading happens.
For example add a div with the following css:

```
.wait-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: wait;
    z-index: 100
}
```

That way the whole screen will have the waiting cursor

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with javascript (probably embedding it into your existent `refreshTable()` function).

first, pass the button object to your function in `onclick` by adding `this`:

```
<asp:Button ID="RefreshBtn" Text="Refresh" OnClick="refreshTable(this)" runat="server"/>
```

Then simply apply the style to it only when the function is called:

```
//the var btn is the button that you clicked
refreshTable(btn){
//...

btn.style.cursor = 'wait';
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the answers above worked for me.  I did however find the answer here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1324613.aspx

So in the Page_load, I added the following line:

```
this.RefreshBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "refreshTable()");
```

then in my refreshTable() I added:

```
document.getElementById("RefreshBtn").style.cursor = "wait";
```